# CQRS materialized view

Tags: microservices, cqrs, materialized-views, saga

We need to implement CQRS in our microservice architecture(SAGA). I have the following doubts regarding the materialized view in the read database.

1. Is CQRS materialized view refers to the actual tables?
2. Suppose we have different formats of reports from the same tables, do we need to keep multiple views?
3. In the future, if we need a schema/format change, how do we incorporate that change into view?
   a) if rebuilding the view is possible, does it take time and resources?
   b) if so, arethere any alternatives

I have gone through many examples. But didn't get a clear picture about materialized view.
Appreciate your answers.

Comment: I would look at your requirements. Implementing CQRS sounds like a solution, not a problem you are trying to solve. Why do you need CQRS?

Comment: Hi @Maxim,

We need to separate read and write requests to separate databases to increase performance.
On referring to many examples online, I could see many mentioned about the materialized views. But didn't get a clear picture.